# Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, collation

I checked the database table and found it was in `latin1_swedish_ci` so i've changed it to `utf8_general_ci` then I changed the collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` for all the fields.

Still it's giving me the same error.

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Thanks,

Comment: check again..there is somewhere you might missed to change it to `utf8_general_ci` ..

Comment: Thanks, found one field in `utf8_unicode_ci` and converted it into the  `utf8_general_ci` and its working fine now...

Comment: I knew that..you must be missing one field..anyways..congo..cheers

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71659466/4335210 check my post for this problem. maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 34):

so the answer is simple. It seems you missed the change as stated by MKJ ^^ but the actual syntax to alter your tables looks like this.

```
alter table `dbname`.`tablename` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Applied as an individual script or at the end of your create table statement you should be able to relate all related tables back to the same charset

Answer (score 5):

```
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

add to the query end, like this;

```
SELECT * FROM table COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```