# Search in two mysql tables with non identical tables (keyword search)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make my keyword search in two mysql tables. my tables don't have any identical column names. But I tried few queries, they didn't work for me.

Keyword IS 07731A0328

I tried this:

```
$sql =  "select a.*, b.* from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.col1=b.htno WHERE a.col1 like '$name'";

$sql =  "select a.*, b.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.col1=b.htno WHERE a.col1 like $name";
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

**TABLE 1**

[image: TABLE 1]

**TABLE2**

[image: TABLE 2]

Comment: "i tried few quiries" - show what exactly, might be easier to help.

Comment: You don't mention what you have tried, what you want to do or the results you expect. How do you expect us to answer? Poor show. Please read the FAQ for questions on this site.

Comment: @MichałPowaga i have updated the question with queries i have used before. please check now.

Comment: @webnoob i have updated the question with queries i have used before. please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2 
WHERE Table1.col1=Table2.htnon AND Table1.col1 = "07731A0328"
```

Comment: How does this query give two rows depicted by OP?

Comment: @peterm OP is asking for all rows from table1, not 2 rows.

Comment: got same error :( `Database Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='  `

Comment: @user2457175 You never said you got this error. Change the collation of anyone table and its respective column also.

Comment: bro now my collection is `utf8_unicode_ci` to what should i change it.. didn't have idea about this collection and things... kindly please let me know

Comment: See this link for changing the collation http://www.hosting.com/support/mysql/change-the-collation-on-a-mysql-database-via-phpmyadmin make collation to `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Sorry. I've missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Join is your friend:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.col1=TABLE2.htnon 
WHERE TABLE1.col1 = "07731A0328"
```

Comment: got an error. `Database Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' `

Comment: I would guess that the text in col1 and htnon have different formats. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819159/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-general-ci-implicit-and-utf8-unicode-ci-implic for the solution to this problem